# WordCloud Only Supported for TrueType fonts

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, visualization, lda, truetype

I am trying to generate a word cloud using the WordCloud module in Python, however I see the following error whenever I call `.generate`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/6db3226b-5f96-4257-980d-bb8ec1dad8e7/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    wc.generate("foo bar foo bar hello world")
  File "/home/mjc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.py", line 639, in generate
    return self.generate_from_text(text)
  File "/home/mjc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.py", line 621, in generate_from_text
    self.generate_from_frequencies(words)
  File "/home/mjc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.py", line 453, in generate_from_frequencies
    self.generate_from_frequencies(dict(frequencies[:2]),
  File "/home/mjc/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.py", line 508, in generate_from_frequencies
    box_size = draw.textbbox((0, 0), word, font=transposed_font, anchor="lt")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 671, in textbbox
    raise ValueError("Only supported for TrueType fonts")
ValueError: Only supported for TrueType fonts
```

As it stands, I am trying to create a very simple example WordCloud

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
wc = WordCloud(background_color="white", font_path="./arial.ttf", width=800, height=400)
wc.generate("foo bar foo bar hello world")
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(wc)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Where `arial.ttf` is downloaded from https://www.freefontspro.com/14454/arial.ttf and placed in the same directory as `test.py`. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and Python 3.10.6.

I was expecting to generate a word cloud from the input "foo bar foo bar hello world", however see the error `ValueError: Only supported for TrueType fonts` despite passing a ttf to the `font_path` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce your error with Python 3.10 even after downloading the same font - though I am on macOS.

The only thing I can imagine is that your **PIL** doesn't support TrueType fonts, so you can check with:

```
python3 -m PIL
```

**Sample Output**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Pillow 9.4.0
Python 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:19) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL
Binary modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok, compiled for 9.4.0
--- TKINTER support ok, loaded 8.6
--- FREETYPE2 support ok, loaded 2.13.0             <--- HERE
--- LITTLECMS2 support ok, loaded 2.14
--- WEBP support ok, loaded 1.3.0
--- WEBP Transparency support ok
--- WEBPMUX support ok
--- WEBP Animation support ok
--- JPEG support ok, compiled for libjpeg-turbo 2.1.4
--- OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support ok, loaded 2.5.0
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok, loaded 1.2.13
--- LIBTIFF support ok, loaded 4.5.0
--- RAQM (Bidirectional Text) support ok, loaded 0.9.0, fribidi 1.0.12, harfbuzz 7.1.0
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT (Quantization method) support not installed
--- XCB (X protocol) support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BLP
Extensions: .blp
Features: open, save, encode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BMP image/bmp
Extensions: .bmp
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BUFR
Extensions: .bufr
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
CUR
Extensions: .cur
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DCX
Extensions: .dcx
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DDS
Extensions: .dds
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
DIB image/bmp
Extensions: .dib
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
EPS application/postscript
Extensions: .eps, .ps
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FITS
Extensions: .fit, .fits
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FLI
Extensions: .flc, .fli
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
FTEX
Extensions: .ftc, .ftu
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GBR
Extensions: .gbr
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GIF image/gif
Extensions: .gif
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
GRIB
Extensions: .grib
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
HDF5
Extensions: .h5, .hdf
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ICNS image/icns
Extensions: .icns
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ICO image/x-icon
Extensions: .ico
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IM
Extensions: .im
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IMT
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
IPTC
Extensions: .iim
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
JPEG image/jpeg
Extensions: .jfif, .jpe, .jpeg, .jpg
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
JPEG2000 image/jp2
Extensions: .j2c, .j2k, .jp2, .jpc, .jpf, .jpx
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MCIDAS
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MPEG video/mpeg
Extensions: .mpeg, .mpg
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
MSP
Extensions: .msp
Features: open, save, decode
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PCD
Extensions: .pcd
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PCX image/x-pcx
Extensions: .pcx
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIXAR
Extensions: .pxr
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PNG image/png
Extensions: .apng, .png
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PPM image/x-portable-anymap
Extensions: .pbm, .pgm, .pnm, .ppm
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PSD image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
Extensions: .psd
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SGI image/sgi
Extensions: .bw, .rgb, .rgba, .sgi
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SPIDER
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SUN
Extensions: .ras
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TGA image/x-tga
Extensions: .icb, .tga, .vda, .vst
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TIFF image/tiff
Extensions: .tif, .tiff
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WEBP image/webp
Extensions: .webp
Features: open, save, save_all
--------------------------------------------------------------------
WMF
Extensions: .emf, .wmf
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XBM image/xbm
Extensions: .xbm
Features: open, save
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XPM image/xpm
Extensions: .xpm
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
XVTHUMB
Features: open
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or, more speedily - since we are only interested in *"freetype"* lines:

```
python3 -m PIL | grep -i type
```

Then you may need to install `freetype` with a command something like - not too sure of the exact package name:

```
sudo apt install libfreetype6
```

Comment: Perfect! My `libfreetype6` was out of date and needed to be manually updated!

Comment: I had an identical error message in several Windows machines (Win7, Python 3.8.7, Pillow 9.1.1 & Win10, Python 3.9.9, Pillow 9.0.1), both with `python3 -m PIL` output: `--- FREETYPE2 support ok`. The solution was upgrading Pillow to 9.5.0: `pip install --upgrade pillow` as @kbogdan suggests in another answer

Answer (score 13):

These work for me:

```
pip install --upgrade pip 

pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

Tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: I tried installing/upgrading pillow but am still running into the same problem

Comment: This worked for me, although I overlooked your answer and tried first the accepted one. Thanks! BTW, not sure if this is relevant, but in my case (Windows) `pillow` package name is in lowercase

Comment: Seems like `pillow` is the solution for Windows and `libfreetype6` for Ubuntu. I've kept Mark's answer as accepted as it helped in my case.

Comment: I ran into the same problem after updating word cloud. In my context (jupyter notebook started from a WSL shell) none of the workarounds helped unfortunately. `libfreetype6` is up to date and I updated `pillow` to version 9.5.0. However, I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.6, re-installed wordcloud 1.8.0 (pip install wordcloud==1.8.0), issue fixed. Latest version of WordCloud does not support Python3.6 as per official docs.

Answer (score 0):

tried this solution 1

upgrading PIP and  Pillow didn't work for me like many of others

tried this solution 2 - worked very well for me

Using Python 3.6, re-installed wordcloud 1.8.0 (pip install wordcloud==1.8.0), issue fixed. Latest version of WordCloud does not support Python3.6 as per official docs.

Comment: This should be a comment on existing answers. Do not use "answers" unless you have a new answer, that wasn't already given, to bring. Especially not to testify that this given answers works or doesn't work for you.